# Error while loading wave dashboard embed vf page in communities

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

This dashboard doesn't exist, has been deleted, or you may not have access to it.

Given permission set to dealer profile and assigned proper license as well.

Comment: What license type are you using for using wave in communities ?

Comment: Also please specify license type you are using for community user ?

Comment: Permission set license : Analytics Cloud - Wave Community Users

Comment: System permission in permission set : View Analytics on Communities pages.

Comment: User license of Profile : "Partner Community". Given viewer permission from Wave App to dealer as well, VF Page permission to profile also given. Any idea. What is being missed ?

Comment: Have you shared your dashboard as explained in docs https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_app_communities.htm&type=5

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : Yup, Gave viewer permission to partner user for complete app as well as dashboard.